# Javascript Prototype What is Correct?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Hey guys i have a question regarding prototype in javascript.

Which of the following is the correct and best way to use prototype and why?

```
var myClass = function(){
this.anotherFunction();
}

myClass.prototype.anotherFunction = function(){
  console.log('my prototype function');
}
var foo = new myClass(); // which automaticaly performs the function
```

OR

```
var myClass = function(){
}

myClass.prototype.anotherFunction = function(){
  console.log('my prototype function');
}
var foo = new myClass();
foo.anotherFunction(); // performs the function only when called
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not one or the other. Choose what's best for your situation, one will execute as soon as you create an instance while the other will not.

Comment: Both will not work as your `var` statements have errors.

Comment: The two examples are not related to your question.

Comment: @user3539582 Now, the important question. What exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first implementation calls a method directly from the constructor. These methods are quite often some kind of initialization methods that build the needed inner state of the `this` context. In non JavaScript appropriate OOP speak this would mean that a method is called directly from your class constructor that builds up some initial state.

The second implementation exposes the prototype function `anotherFunction` as part of the public interface.

In short: Both variants are correct but implement different concepts

Comment: So the first example does not generate duplicates of the prototype function?

Comment: Why should it duplicate something? It calls anotherFunction only

Comment: Ok thanks alot mate! Sorry i just learned about the prototype forgive me if i ask some weird questions.

Comment: The reason i ask is because when you say new object you copy everything thats what i did before wrapping all my functions inside a function and then making a new object of that one ergo duplicating everything so with that being said using the Prototype avoids this matter?